# Problem while installing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 as a user with Administrator rights

Tags: ms-sql

I am using Microsoft Windows XP service pack 3

User Accounts: VC3(Type: Administrator) and Administrator

**Question**

I am trying to install the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 in VC3

After half of the installation it shows `"you are user you dont have permission to install"`
which it will shows `"failed"` for

`"Database Engine"`

`"Analysis Services"`

`"Reporting Services"`

When i am trying to install the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 in Administrator

After half of the installation it shows `"failed"` for

`"Management Tools-Basic"`

`"Management Tools-Complete"`

`"SQL Client Connectivity SDk"`

`"Microsoft Sync Framework"`

Please tell me the solution for this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am recently find that my system is effected with virus which it may removes some important files in  the system. The setup files of the Microsoft SQL Server is also located in that system. When i am tried to install from the DVD it works and there is no problem in the installation